# Как правильно пишется слово грошевой или грошовой?

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, как правильно пишется Товар по **грошевой** цене или Товар по **грошовой** цене?

Comment: Грошовый. Словарь вам в помощь .http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/lop/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово *грошево́й*, конечно же, имеется в языке. Если верить Нацкорпусу РЯ, то оно употреблялось нечасто и до первой половины двадцатого века.

В толковом словаре Даля (1863—1866):
[грош](https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88)
*Грошево́й* или *грошо́вый*, ценою в грош. У грошевого товара не наживешь (не уторгуешь) рубля.

В толковом словаре Ушакова (1935—1940) — уже только *грошовый*.

У В. В. Набокова ("Дар", 1935—1937):
*...маленький ярмарочный писк **грошевой** истины.*

В когда-то известной песне ["Бригантина"](https://45parallel.net/pavel_kogan/stihi/) (Павел Коган, 1937):
*Пьем за яростных, за непохожих,

За презревших **грошевой** уют.

Вьется по ветру веселый Роджер,

Люди Флинта песенку поют.*

Так что сегодня признаем слово *грошево́й* окончательно устаревшим и будем говорить и писать правильно: *грошо́вый товар, **по грошо́вой цене**, грошо́вое колечко.*

P. S. Если же подразумевалась буква **ё** ("по грошёвой цене"), то все равно "по грошовой".
[Правило](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/groshovyi-ili-groshyovyi.html):
В окончаниях и суффиксах существительных и прилагательных после шипящих «ж», «ш», «ч», «щ» под ударением пишется буква «о», без ударения — буква «е».
Камышовый, ершовый, ковшовый, лапшовый.